# JAVA_HOME points to an invalid Java installation

Tags: java, windows, elasticsearch, java-home

I set JAVA_HOME in my windows 10. When I check java version I get next:

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
```

Although, I can check the javac version:

```
C:\>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_221
```

I can start any jar:

```
D:\>java -jar authTest.jar
Hello world!!!
```

But when I try start elastic search I get an exception:

```
D:\elasticsearch-2.3.0>bin\service.bat install
JAVA_HOME points to an invalid Java installation (no java.exe found in "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221;"). Exiting...
```

But if  set JAVA_HOME manually in console

```
D:\elasticsearch-2.3.0>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221
```

Service start successfully:

```
D:\elasticsearch-2.3.0>bin\service.bat install
Installing service      :  "elasticsearch-service-x64"
Using JAVA_HOME (64-bit):  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221"
The service 'elasticsearch-service-x64' has been installed.
```

But if when I reopen cmd - I need to repeat all steps. Why do I need to set JAVA_HOME each time in cmd?

Comment: Is your env variable set in windows system ?

Comment: Where did you set the JAVA_HOME variable: _User Variables_ or _System Variables_?

Comment: Depending on where the jvm is

Answer (score 1):

If I see right, there is a ";" at the end of your JAVA_HOME path. Running Jars and javac use PATH environment variable, and are not affected by this.

You can delete the trailing ";" by clicking "edit text" when you are in the windows that allows you to add or remove values of your JAVA_HOME.[image: Edit Text Button location]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think PROPERTIES  for JAVA_HOME is not setting which may cause getting this error.
either you can set this in environment variable and then restart your system.
or u open cmd 
run > set and enter
this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You java path might not be defined but the absolute path to the jvm is defined in $PATH so just go in your explorer > this pc > advanced settings > environnement variables > and add a JAVA_HOME variable with the a path to the folder in which the jvm executable is